# Where is the formal semantics of Data Analysis Expressions (DAX) documented?

Tags: dax, formal-semantics

The expressive power of Microsoft’s Data Analysis Expressions (DAX) is really amazing. It is very useful to me … but after several months of practice I am still not fully confident of what my expressions will yield.

Usually when learning a new language I start with a tutorial, then read the user’s manual and then consult formal details in the reference guide. With DAX there are plenty of tutorials, in the form of textbooks, websites, blogs …. but if you want to go in more depth, all the sources I’ve seen so far are informal and just advice to “learn by practice”. Even the [official reference by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/) , or the excellent https://dax.guide/ site, just give verbal explanations of DAX functions, but do not precisely explain what is a “context switch”, a “table filter” or other constructs.

Part of the confusion seems to come from the fact that DAX is often presented as a “functional language”, and is often paired with M, another language from Microsoft for expressing steps of data extraction and transformation. M is a truly functional language and has a [very well-written formal specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/). By contrast, DAX only has a functional *syntax* at the surface, but the *semantics* is not functional at all : DAX functions are evaluated within an implicit context, and many functions *modify that context*.

In a truly functional language, the result of a function only depends on the input values; and each argument to the function is computed independently *before* calling the function. In DAX it is very different; my gross understanding of it is as follows :

1. There is an implicit *data model*, which consists of *tables* and *relations*
2. Each table has an implicit set of *reachable columns*, which is the union of columns from all related tables
3. There is an implicit *filter context*, which is an assembly of Boolean conditions on reachable columns
4. Some of the DAX functions do not return a result, but they temporarily modify the implicit data model (for ex. CALCULATETABLE, USERELATIONSHIP), or temporarily modify the implicit filter context (for ex. FILTER, ALL).
5. Some functions *quote* expressions in some of their arguments, in the sense of LISP QUOTE. So for example the second argument in  `SUMX(table, [m1] * [m2])` does not mean “compute [m1], compute [2], multiply them and pass them to SUMX”; it rather means “create a new quoted expression ‘([m1] * [m2]), and pass that expression to SUMX which will iterate over the table, modify the implicit context at each row, evaluate the expression in that modified context, and then sum up the whole result”.
6. Some functions modify their arguments through *syntactic sugar rules*; for example `CALCULATE(table, [column]=99)` is a shortcut for `CALCULATE(table, FILTER(ALL(table[column), [column]=99))`.

So this is quite different from a functional language!

Of course the presentation above is just a very general direction for approaching a precise description of DAX semantics; it would need to be refined in full detail.

Is that way of seeing things correct ? Is there any published reference that already describes DAX at this level of precision ?

Comment: Maybe the question doesn't fit the outdated community guidelines, but it's damn right!

Comment: What helped me get to the next level of DAX was a book "Definitive Guide to DAX" from Marco Russo. It has the depth you are seeking. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07TS4FPZM

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. This is indeed a very helpful book, with plenty of valuable examples. But this is also one of the main sources that presents DAX as a "functional language" similar to Excel formulas, which led me to a wrong way of thinking until I understood that the semantics of DAX function calls is in fact quite different from Haskell or Excel function calls.